# How to get different language file fpr same language, different condition in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, locale, lang

For example , I would like to have the English , but one is American english and the other is British english.

but instead of making two language (as many logic has written before, it needs great effort to adjust the code),

is that possible to only specific different language file when meet the condition?

e.g.

```
if ($region->us) {
  //set english as language code
  //load american_en file
} else if ($region->en) {
 //set english as language code
  //load britsh_en file
}
```

Comment: yes.  if you have a 'en' folder in languages, just have a cant_spell and a british file and conditionally load it as required.  language packs are simply a key value pair. so it will work the rest out.